# How to convert an expression of several variables into an operator

Tags: symbolic, operators

Given the expression

[image]

How can I define the following operator like

```
g[u_, v_] := eq1
```

The correct definition is

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
f = Derivative[1, 0][Head@#1] @@ List @@ #1 + 
    Derivative[0, 2][Head@#2] @@ List @@ #2 &;

f[u[x, y], v[x, y]]
```

[image]

```
f[x[u, v], y[u, v]]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Using `eq1`

```
Clear[f2, f3]

eq1 = Derivative[1, 0][u][x, y] +
   Derivative[0, 2][v][x, y];

f2[u_Symbol, v_Symbol] := Evaluate@eq1
f2[u2_, v2_] := Module[{u = Head[u2], v = Head[v2]}, 
  Evaluate@eq1]

f2[s, t]
```

[image]

```
f2[s[x, y], t[x, y]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I need to use the expression eq1 to define the operator.